# How do you change every character in a file into its ASCII number? Python

Tags: python, ascii

```
with open('s.txt', 'r') as f: s = f.read() 

for word in s:

    val = ord(word)
```

I'm trying to convert every character in the text file into its ASCII number, however it is only displaying one number when printed. Thank you.

Comment: So far your code does not print anything.

Comment: You may not be able to convert every character in the text file into an ASCII number, because it might not contain only ASCII characters.

Comment: @kindall No idea what you're talking about 

Answer (score 1):

You are constantly overwriting your `val`, so you will actually only end up with the last ascii value. Also, for the sake of naming things properly, your iterator should be something like `char` or `c`. Using `word` is misleading.

You can do this:

```
new_data = " ".join(str(ord(c)) for c in f.read())
```

`f.read()` giving a string, we iterate over the string, grabbing each character, and then calling `ord` on each. Then cast it to a `str` (since ord returns an int) and finally `join` to change it back to the string of ascii values.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "hello 123 &^@!)(" #this is the example string

for character in list(text): #loops through every character
    print(ord(character)) #print the ascii value of the character
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning `val` every iteration, you should be appending it to an array or concatentating a string.  e.g.:

```
with open('s.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_contents = f.read() 

ascii_vals = [ord(char) for char in file_contents]
print(ascii_vals)
```

Which is equivalent to the following if you're not yet familiar with list comprehensions (which execute a bit more efficiently).

```
with open('s.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_contents = f.read() 

ascii_vals = []
for char in file_contents]
    ascii_vals.append(ord(char))
print(ascii_vals)
```

Since `ord` gives an int value you'll have to do string formatting to convert back from int to string.  How you do that depends how you want to present the data.

Don't forget if you're reading a file in utf-8 format you may get characters that go beyond what ASCII defines.